# How do I use thrift_client library hook feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thrift

I'm using [thrift_client 0.8.1 library](https://github.com/twitter/thrift_client/blob/master/lib/thrift_client/abstract_thrift_client.rb). And it supports some hook interfaces.

```
client = ThriftClient.new(FooService, host)

client.add_callback :before_method do |*args|
  ActionController::Base.logger.info instance_eval("@current_server")
  logger.info args.inspect
end

client.add_callback :post_connect do |client|
  logger.info "A thrift server connection has been made<#{client.current_server}>"
end
```

Everytime calling a method, I would like to write log the information of thrift server.
So I installed a `:before method` hook but I think `instance_eval("@current_server")` doesn't work as I expected. The `@current_server` is an instance variable in the `ThriftClient` class. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the :before_method callback is invoked within the ThriftClient instance context. This is the invocation of :before_method:

```
  def do_callbacks(callback_type_sym, *args)
    return unless @callbacks[callback_type_sym]
    @callbacks[callback_type_sym].each do |callback|
      callback.call(*args)
    end
  end
```

The :before_method CB is invoked with the method name. For :post_connect it is the client instance.